# webpack-cli and webpack-command together

Tags: webpack

If I install `webpack-cli` i can't run webpack

*You have installed webpack-cli and webpack-command together.*

```
"webpack": "^4.43.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
"webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
```

When uninstall it I can't run `webpack-dev-server`

*The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI*

Answer (score 2):

I guess I got solution wiil use `webpack-cli`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack-cli --config webpack/webpack.prod.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.dev.js",
    "test": "jest --config jest.config.json"
},
```